# Decrypting pass at login time failed using simpleCrypto Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am decrypting password at the time of login.But Login failed because crypto.Compute is generating new pass every time which is not equal to the enrypted password that is stored in db.
Here is my code.
Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Authentication log)
    {
             var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
             Login ULogin = new Login();

              if (ModelState.IsValid)
                  {
                      if 
                            (ULogin.Validate(log.Email,crypto.Compute(log.Password)))
            {
               // FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(log.Email, log.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");



            }
        }
                else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login failed..");



        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show an example what it does for same values when passed while creating a password and then while comparing it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are utilizing the salt feature.

When you generate a password hash, if you do not specify a salt, the library will generate and use one for you. You should store this salt with your hashed password and use it back in your hashing for validating the user. If you don't do this, everytime you try to generate a hash, a brand new salt will be generated and used, which means a whole different password hash will be computed.